# Where is the tls command?

Tags: ssl, docker, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I use Visual Studio 2015 to publish a docker image to a Linux server. The similar [step](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PublishingAnASPNET5AppToDockerOnLinuxWithVisualStudio.aspx) is on the link.

I get a failed message when you attempt to validate the connection to your Docker host in the Publish Web dialog box.

So I followed the [help.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vs-azure-tools-docker-troubleshooting-docker-errors/)

There is a command which is `--tls -H tcp://contoso.cloudapp.net:2376 info`

I am not sure in which place to run this command. Because if I run it under `C:\Windows\system32`. It can not be found `--tls`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### There is a command which is `--tls -H tcp://contoso.cloudapp.net:2376 info`

> Because if I run it under C:\Windows\system32. It can not be found --tls.

There is a mistake in the [help page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vs-azure-tools-docker-troubleshooting-docker-errors/) you linked to.

`--tls -H tcp://contoso.cloudapp.net:2376 info` are the arguments to `docker`, and `docker` is missing from the command line.

So your command should be as follows:

```
docker--tls -H tcp://contoso.cloudapp.net:2376 info
```

I've reported the error to Microsoft.

The other [step page](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PublishingAnASPNET5AppToDockerOnLinuxWithVisualStudio.aspx) you linked to shows a (correct?) `docker` command:

```
C:\>docker --tls -H=tcp://hanseldocker.cloudapp.net:2376 ps
```

The above command, of course, demonstrates using `ps` instead of `info`.

Notes:

- It looks like this command is wrong as well. I don't think it should have the `=` character but should have a `space` instead ...